# ifelse for multiple combinations for two variables

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have two variables like below:

```
var a = "active"  //[two possible value active/inactive]
var b = "inactive" //[three possible values active/locked/disabled]
var outcome = ""

    if(a=="active" && b=="active") 
      outcome = "a";
    elif(a=="active" && b=="locked") 
      outcome = "b"
    elif(a=="active" && b=="disabled")
      outcome = "c"
    elif(a=="inactive" && b=="active")
      outcome = "d"
    elif(a=="inactive" && b=="disabled")
      outcome = "e"
    elif(a=="inactive" && b=="locked")
      outcome = "f"
```

What is the most efficient way of describing the possible outcomes other than using ifelse checking for different conditions in JS?Please suggest.

Comment: Your last condition `elif(a=="inactive" && b=="active")` won't be triggered since it's repeated earlier on. Is there an issue with using an if-statement? What type of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @NickParsons I corrected my post. I am just figuring if there is any alternative way to design code for two variables with multiple combination values having different outcomes defined.

Comment: elif is not JavaScript. You need `else if`

Answer (score 4):

You could make your logic more data-driven by using an object, for example:

```js
var outcomeMap = {
  active: {
    active: "a",
    locked: "b",
    disabled: "c"
  },
  inactive: {
    active: "d",
    locked: "e",
    disabled: "f",
  }
};
```

You can then set your `outcome` variable by accessing this object using `a`, and then accessing the nested object's value, for example:

```js
var outcome = outcomeMap[a][b];
```

Note that if `a` can be anything other than the values you have mentioned, it's best to check that `outcomeMap[a]` isn't `undefined` before accessing `b`. If your environment supports it, that can be done using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `outcomeMap[a]?.[b];`

Alternatively, you could set up arrays with your possible combinations, and then loop through them to check if your combinations match. You can then index into your results (`outcomes`), based on your current index if you find a result, for example:

```js
function getOutcome(a, b) {
  const aVals = ['active', 'inactive'];
  const bVals = ['active', 'locked', 'disabled'];
  const outcomes = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']];

  for(const [i, aVal] of aVals.entries()) {
    for(const [j, bVal] of bVals.entries()) {
      if (aVal == a && bVal == b) {
        return outcomes[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  // return ''; if you want a default value of empty string
}
const outcome = getOutcome('inactive','locked');
console.log(outcome);
```

Note that neither of these approaches are more efficient than using an if-statement. However, they should be easier to scale if you get more possiblilities.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to simply add the string values of a and b and then define the possible outcomes in an object. For simplicity, I have not included all options in your example:

```
var get_outcome = {
    'activeactive': 'a',
    'activelocked': 'b',
    'activedisabled': 'c'
}
```

Then you can simply get your outcome with:

```
var outcome = get_outcome[a+b]
```

Although, if else statements are quite fast in JavaScript, this might be an option if you have many elif statements.

Answer (score 0):

If your variables have finite number of possible values, I would first suggest using enums to store those and make code more readable:

```
const StatusA = {
    Active: "active",
    Inactive: "inactive"
}

const StatusB = {
    Active: "active",
    Locked: "locked",
    Disabled: "disabled"
}

var a = StatusA.Active;
var b = StatusB.Disabled;
```

You could then use string concatenation to transform your elseifs to a switch case:

```
switch (a + b) {
    case StatusA.Active + StatusB.Active: 
        console.log('outcome A');
        break;
    case StatusA.Active + StatusB.Locked: 
        console.log('outcome B');
        break;
    case StatusA.Active + StatusB.Disabled: 
        console.log('outcome C');
        break;
    case StatusA.Inactive + StatusB.Active: 
        console.log('outcome D');
        break;
    case StatusA.Inactive + StatusB.Locked: 
        console.log('outcome E');
        break;
    case StatusA.Inactive + StatusB.Disabled: 
        console.log('outcome F');
        break;
}
```